# Could not generate JMeter HTML reports in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I'm using HTML Publisher plugin to generate JMeter HTML reports in jenkins.However I could see no index.html file generated at the build level or location mentioned for archiving.
[image]

Though I could see my build status Success i did not find html report.

```
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level 
C:\Users\Surya\.jenkins\workspace\MySampleJMeterProject to C:\Users\Surya\.jenkins\jobs\MySampleJMeterProject\builds\13\htmlreports\HTML_Report
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please Help..!!

Comment: in publishing option you have checkboxes that can help : Keep past HTML reports  / Always link to last build  /Allow missing report

Comment: i have tried that options too...i could see only htmlpublisher-wrapper.html in the folder along with jtl and jmeter log